# Should I use localhost for my API when deploying .net MVC and api on the same IIS server

Tags: .net, api, iis, model-view-controller

I have technically 1 app which is .net Core mvc. The API layer is a separate app (.net solution). I have assigned the API its own port and in the appsettings.json file on the MVC project it calls the IP/port for it's API calls. Would it make sense to just have it call the localhost/port? I feel it should respond faster.

Comment: unless you don't need your API accessible outside the server, using localhost looks fine

Answer (score 0):

Use localhost is a bit faster than a domain domain. Because resolving localhost always faster than resolving a DNS CNAME from DNS server. So if you don't need extneral access, localhost is enough. However, if you need to expose your website to public, then you'd better use a domain name because we don't want to expose IP address directly.